# WPF Caliburn.Micro - Best way to navigate in Single Window Application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

1. My history:

I'm developing a WPF application, which will run in full screen on the touch screen. Navigation in my application can be done only by clicking a button on each page ("back" or "logout").

This is not a Universal App, but it looks like.

2. Assumptions of the project:

   - Application will run on full screen mode in Windows 7 on the touch screen.
   - I'm using Caliburn.Micro MVVM framework.
3. Problem and question:

I've got 1 window and 3 UserControl (and ViewModels) [Concept art](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbpLS.jpg)

```
 Window ShellView
     UserControl LoginView
     UserControl OrdersView
     UserControl OrderDetailView
```

When application starting, i'm set LoginView as default and load it by using CM Conductor ActivateItem method, but i don't know **how to set another View from UserControl like LoginView**

I have read: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545750/wpf-caliburn-micro-mvvm-navigation) but this doesn't cover my case
and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15722990/3984428) but it's to hard to understand for me.

My ideas:

- make static method in ShellViewModel like:

ShellViewModel

```
public static void setOrdersView() {
    ActivateItem(new OrdersViewModel());
    // Error : An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Caliburn.Micro.ConductorBase<object>.ActivateItem(object)
}
ShellViewModel.setOrdersView();
```

- make listener in ShellViewModel and send event from child ViewModel ( but now i don't know how to achieve it)

**Question: What is the best way to handle navigation in this case?**

4. Application architecture:

ShellView

```
<Window>
   <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />
</Window>
```

ShellViewModel

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>, IShell
{

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        LoadDefault();
    }    

    public void LoadDefault()
    {
        ActivateItem(new LoginViewModel());
    }
}
```

LoginView

```
<UserControl>
    <Button x:Name="Login" />
</UserControl>
```

LoginViewModel

```
public class LoginViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public void Login() {
        if (LoginManager.Login("User", "Password")) {
            // How to redirect user to OrdersView?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have similar applications with one shell window and many activated views inside and some dialog windows.
You should use **EventAggregator** pattern for these needs and Caliburn already has implementation.

**How to Achieve**:

Minimum `Shell` signature

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>,
    IHandle<ChangePageMessage>,
    IHandle<OpenWindowMessage>
```

You need two fields inside (second one is for dialogs):

```
public IEventAggregator EventAggregator { get; private set; }
public IWindowManager WindowManager { get; private set; }
```

I've set single instances of that objects through IoC. You can also define them as Singletons.
EventAggregator needs subscription on object where `IHandle`s are implemented.

```
EventAggregator.Subscribe(this); //You should Unsubscribe when message handling is no longer needed
```

Handlers implementation:

```
public void Handle(ChangePageMessage message) {
    var instance = IoC.GetInstance(message.ViewModelType, null);//Or just create viewModel by type
    ActivateItem(instance);
}

public void Handle(OpenWindowMessage message) {
    var instance = IoC.GetInstance(message.ViewModelType, null);//Or just create viewModel by type
    WindowManager.ShowWindow(instance);
}
```

Messages for event aggregator can be only marker classes but sometimes it is useful to pass more parameters like ours `OpenWindowMessage` and `ChangePageMessage` classes - they are absolutely similar by content, so for example:

```
public class OpenWindowMessage {

    public readonly Type ViewModelType;

    public OpenWindowMessage(Type viewModelType) {
        ViewModelType = viewModelType;
    }
}
```

All your viewModels can also subscribe to EventAggregator instance and Handle some messages for communication, or even for initial parameters. I have something like `MyViewModelInitMessage` classes almost for every viewModel, and just use two publish methods together.

```
EventAggregator.Publish(new ChangePageMessage(typeof(MyViewModel)));
EventAggregator.Publish(new MyViewModelInitMessage("...all needed parameters"));
```

So when I publish those two - mine `ViewModel` will be activated, then it subscribes to `EventAggregator`(*don't forget to do that or second message handling never occurs*), and will handle its `InitMessage` right after.

Now with **EventAggregator** you can send messages between all ViewModels that are currently subscribed to it.

That seems pretty common solution.